# Is there a way to `ls()` all `S4` classes I've created?

Tags: r, r-s4

```
setClass('A')
setClass('B', contains='A')
setClass('C')
setClass('D', contains=c('C','B'))
ls()
```

In some sense I've "created" four "things", but because I haven't instantiated any of these classes yet, I can't see any of them.

Is there a way to see the available classes? Maybe an `env` in which `S4` classes defined so far are stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class definitions are stored in variables preceded by `.__C__`, so

```
> grep(".__C__", ls(all=TRUE), value=TRUE)
[1] ".__C__A" ".__C__B" ".__C__C" ".__C__D"
```

For classes defined in a package, look in the package namespace, e.g.,

```
> library(quantmod)
> symbols <- ls("package:quantmod", all=TRUE)
> grep(".__C__", symbols, value=TRUE)
[1] ".__C__chob"           ".__C__chobTA"         ".__C__quantmod"      
[4] ".__C__quantmodReturn" ".__C__tradeLog"
```

Comment: thank you!! Hadley was not kidding, you are the `S4` answer master :)

Comment: Now I notice, if I `require(quantmod)` (which uses S4), then `ls(all=TRUE)` doesn't import their S4 objects such as `chob`. What's the difference?